# Is it safe to concatenate AVI files with video fourcc xvid, mp42, dx50?

Tags: video, codec, avi, fourcc

I have a bunch of AVI files with the same audio codec, video resolution, but the video codecs are different: they have fourcc xvid, mp42 and dx50. Is it safe to concatenate them, i.e. is there a video decoder which is compatible with all these? Which fourcc should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of these things is not like the others: mp42 is not the same as xvid or dx50. The latter 2 are MPEG-4 part 2 while mp42 is a custom, incompatible variation by Microsoft.

Comment: Is it possible to convert mp42 to dx50 without losing (any) quality? Can you recommend software for that?

Comment: A decade ago, I heard of someone working on software to perform this very task, but I don't know if anything was released. It may or may not be possible to losslessly transcode MS MPEG-4v2 (mp42) -> MPEG-4 part 2; I'm not immediately familiar with the details of both bitstreams. I'll ask around about this, though.